# How exactly get and install Wolfram Engine 14.0 under macOS?

Tags: free-wolfram-engine

The page https://www.wolfram.com/engine/ shows only 3 ways to insal the Wolfram Engine. The one shown for macOS, using homebrew.

Although I hesitate to use homebrew —since I use MacPorts (and then using also homebrew could get all kinds of library versions, etc., hopelessly muddled betweeen homebrew and MacPorts) — I did try the displayed command:

`brew install --cask wolfram-engine`

However, that seems to install wolfram-engine version 13.2 instead of 14.0 !!

Another option listed is to use Docker: docker pull wolframresearch/wolframengine. Although I have docker installed under macOS Sonoma, the command fails with error: "Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///Users/murray/.docker/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?"

What exactly does one do there? And can I then run the Wolfram Engine directly from the Terminal command line, or would I have to somewhow start Docker each time (which I would *not* want to do).

Or could it be that just using homebrew for downloading the wolfram-engine would cause not issues with MacPorts? And if so, how do I get version 14.0?

Comment: I would simply click the Download button, which should provide a 14.0.0 "Download Manager" app. There is no requirement to use the homebrew or docker installation methods and these have not yet been updated to the latest version anyway, although it should happen in the near future.

Comment: I was caught by Safari's excessive security! Pressing the "Start Download" button for Wolfram Engine in Safari does nothing and just continues to show the "via Package Manager" option". But with Google Chrome the download button works.